# Is it possible to fire a request on mongodb after 30days?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

My current project right now is something like digital wallet, let's say I  have 1000 and I want to add 5% automatically after 30days. I'm using Nodejs Express and Reactnative.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cronjob. Checkout [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda).
It's great for this purpose. It uses mongodb.